# "Send to mobile" notification on facebook app page does not redirect to Google Play

Tags: facebook, notifications

I have developed one android app "Smarter App" which I am trying to integrate to facebook. Now I am getting app page with "Go to app" and "send to mobile" button below cover image. On "Send to mobile" click, it sent notification on my mobile. But when I click on the notification ("Smarter Car for android is ready to use on your mobile. Start using"), it does not go to google app store from where I can install this app.

Comment: ...and please post the code used to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help from one facebook developer.

Solution : Set a mobile URL in your developer settings, and then make that redirect to app store.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Native Android App` settings in your developer settings for your app. Be sure to include both the Package name and Class Name for it to work properly.