# Getting "page isn't available" when clicking on Facebook App link on a post for Android only Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently integrating an Android app with Facebook. When sharing an image from my app and viewing the post from a webbrowser it displays at the bottom of the post: "X minutes ago via My App Name". This is normal behavior however clicking the "My App Name" link takes me to a page of the form:

"https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=XXX"

The page simply displays "Sorry, this page isn't available. The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed."

When clicking on the image in the facebook app for android (there is no "X minutes ago via My App Name" in the android facebook app), either the app opens if it is installed or the user is taken to the download page.This is the functionality I want.

If I then go to my developer console and click "Add Platform" and "App on Facebook" the page works in a browser however I don't with to implement an App on Facebook. I would like all clicks on "My App Name" in the desktop broswer version to be directed to the community page or to an installer page as it does on android. How can I do this and is there something that I have done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You can find the solution here. It worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513332/send-to-mobile-notification-on-facebook-app-page-does-not-redirect-to-google-p